# Cuando remuevo un fila de 'tr', me genera un error a la hora de sumarlos - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Hola estoy tratando de **Remover** una fila de una tabla, lo **remuevo** visualmente, el código funciona todo bien pero tengo una función que es **sumar**.
Esta función se dispara cada vez que el doy en el botón **agregar**,todo va bien si remuevo la ultima fila pero si `remuevo` la que esta arriba o cualquier otra me sale como **total** **"NaN"** espero me puedan ayduar.
Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO HTML :**

```
<div class="col-xs-7">
     <table id="table_ventas"
        class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover responsive"
            cellspacing="0" width="100%">
             <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th><FONT SIZE=4>#</FONT></th>
                  <th><FONT SIZE=4>Código</FONT></th>
                  <th width="320px"><FONT SIZE=4>Producto</FONT></th>
                  <th><FONT SIZE=4>Precio</FONT></th>
                  <th><FONT SIZE=4>Cantidad</FONT></th>
                  <th><FONT SIZE=4>Subtotal</FONT></th>
                  <th width="5%"></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              </tbody>
             </table>
       <div class="row">
         <div align="center" id="modal_footer">
                 <table id="table_total"
            class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover responsive"
               cellspacing="0" width="100%">
           <thead>
              <tr>
              <td id="total_fila" style="text-align: right;"><strong><FONT SIZE=6>TOTAL : s./ </FONT></strong></th>
                <td id="detalle_total"><strong><FONT color="#1b5e20" SIZE=6> 0 </FONT><th>  
           </tr>
           </thead>
           </table>
            <div align="center">
       <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="cancelar_venta()"
     class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> CANCELAR COMPRA</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**CODIGO DEL BOTON AGREGAR**

```
$("#confirmar_producto").click(function () {
    /* Capturar los valores de los campos */
    var id_producto = $('#id_producto').val();
    var cod_producto = $('#cod_producto').val();
    var precio = $('#precio').val();
    var cantidad = $('#cantidad_comprar').val();
    var producto = $("#producto").text();
    var subtotal = precio * cantidad;
    /* Crear una fila nueva con los datos capturados */
    var cont_fila = ($('#table_ventas tbody').find('tr').length) + 1;
    var fila = '<tr>';
    fila = fila + '<td scope="row">' + cont_fila + '</td>';
    fila = fila + '<td><input type="hidden" id="id_producto_tabla" value="' + id_producto + '"><input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="Codigo_' + cont_fila + '" value="' + cod_producto + '" readonly="readonly" /></td>';//Codigo
    fila = fila + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="Producto_' + cont_fila + '" value="' + producto + '" readonly="readonly" /></td>';//Producto
    fila = fila + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="Precio_' + cont_fila + '" value="' + precio + '" readonly="readonly" /></td>';//Precio
    fila = fila + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="Cantidad_' + cont_fila + '" value="' + cantidad + '" readonly="readonly" /></td>';//Cantidad
    fila = fila + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="Subtotal_' + cont_fila + '" value="' + subtotal + '" readonly="readonly" /></td>';//Subtotal
    fila = fila + '<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="eliminar_fila" onclick="eliminar_detalle(this,' + cont_fila + ');"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x"></i></a></td>';//Eliminar
    fila = fila + '</tr>';
    /* Agregar las futuras filas */
    $("#table_ventas").append(fila);
    /* Despues de agregar limpiar los inputs*/
    limpiar();
    suma_total();
});
```

**CODIGO DE LA FUNCION SUMAR**

```
function suma_total() {

    var cont_fila = ($('#table_ventas tbody').find('tr').length);
    var total_general = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= cont_fila; i++) {
        var subtotal = $('#Subtotal_' + i).val();
        total_general = parseFloat(total_general) + parseFloat(subtotal);
    }
    $("#detalle_total").html("<strong><FONT color='#1b5e20' SIZE=6> " + (total_general * 1).toFixed(2) + " </FONT>");
}
```

**CODGIO DE ELIMINAR**

```
function eliminar_detalle(e, index) {

    $(e).parent().parent().remove();
    suma_total();

}
```

Comment: si en lugar de `$(e).parent().parent().remove();` usas `$(e).closest( "tr" ).remove();`

Comment: Si tuviera una demo real de lo que está pasando sería más fácil ayudarte. Pero pruebe esto: intercambie el `$("#confirmar_producto").click(function () {` para eso `$(document).on( "click", "#confirmar_producto", function() {`

Comment: Y vuelve decir si funciona. Si funcionó, yo puedo crear una respuesta adecuada a su pregunta explicando por qué funcionó.

Comment: Lo ise de otra forma igual gracias (Y)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es la variable `cont_fila`, que se basa en el total de filas + 1.

Supongamos que tienes 3 filas, entonces:

- Los `id` de los `input` para la `1er` fila usan el `1`
- Los `id` de los `input` para la `2da` fila usan el `2`
- Los `id` de los `input` para la `3ra` fila usan el `3`

Supongamos que borras la `1er` fila, al intentar sumar.

Vas buscar el `$('#Subtotal_1').val()`, pero este elemento ya no existe, por lo que el resultado devuelto es `undefined` y es por eso que luego obtienes como total `NaN`.

### Solución:

Modificar la función que **agrega filas**, para que los `input` dejen de usar `id` para identificarlos y en su lugar usen `name`.

```
$("#confirmar_producto").click(function () {
    /* Capturar los valores de los campos */
    var id_producto = $('#id_producto').val();
    var cod_producto = $('#cod_producto').val();
    var precio = $('#precio').val();
    var cantidad = $('#cantidad_comprar').val();
    var producto = $("#producto").text();
    var subtotal = precio * cantidad;
    /* Crear una fila nueva con los datos capturados */
    var cont_fila = ($('#table_ventas tbody').find('tr').length) + 1;
    var fila = '<tr>';
    fila = fila + '<td scope="row">' + cont_fila + '</td>';
    fila = fila + '<td><input type="hidden" name="id_producto_tabla" value="' + id_producto + '"><input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="Codigo" value="' + cod_producto + '" readonly="readonly" /></td>';//Codigo
    fila = fila + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="Producto" value="' + producto + '" readonly="readonly" /></td>';//Producto
    fila = fila + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="Precio" value="' + precio + '" readonly="readonly" /></td>';//Precio
    fila = fila + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="Cantidad" value="' + cantidad + '" readonly="readonly" /></td>';//Cantidad
    fila = fila + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="Subtotal" value="' + subtotal + '" readonly="readonly" /></td>';//Subtotal
    fila = fila + '<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="eliminar_fila" onclick="eliminar_detalle(this);"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x"></i></a></td>';//Eliminar
    fila = fila + '</tr>';
    /* Agregar las futuras filas */
    $("#table_ventas").append(fila);
    /* Despues de agregar limpiar los inputs*/
    limpiar();
    suma_total();
});
```

Luego modificar la función **suma_total** para que busque los `input` por su `name`.

```
function suma_total() {
  var $trs = $('#table_ventas tbody').children();
  var cont_fila = $trs.length;
  var total_general = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < cont_fila; i++) {

    var subtotal = $trs.eq(i).find('input[name="Subtotal"]').val();
    total_general += parseFloat(subtotal);
  }
  $("#detalle_total").html("<strong><FONT color='#1b5e20' SIZE=6> " + (total_general * 1).toFixed(2) + " </FONT>");
}
```

Comment: Alguna solución sin modificar el código ya que a la hora de guardarlo no sabría como hacerlo :s

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores, en lugar de eliminar las filas, podrías ocultarlas y en base a esta condición evaluar si sumarlas/guardarlas/etc o no. De todas formas modificar el script para guardarlas debería ser similar al de sumarlas (buscar las `inputs` por su `name`)

Answer (score 0):

Tu for está mal, tienes `i <= cont_fila` y debe de ser `i < cont_fila` recuerda que los arreglos son base 0, si tienes 4 TR van del 0 al 3 y al querer leer el valor de un row que no existe tendras un undefined.

```
function suma_total() {

var cont_fila = ($('#table_ventas tbody').find('tr').length); //Tienes el TOTAL de TR
var total_general = 0;
//Tienes que ser i < cont_fila
for (var i = 1; i <= cont_fila; i++) {
    var subtotal = $('#Subtotal_' + i).val(); //la ultima iteración será undefined
    //Tienes que validar que exista subtotal 
    total_general = parseFloat(total_general) + parseFloat(subtotal);
    }
$("#detalle_total").html("<strong><FONT color='#1b5e20' SIZE=6> " + (total_general * 1).toFixed(2) + " </FONT>");
}
```

Prueba con esto

```
function suma_total() {

var cont_fila = ($('#table_ventas tbody').find('tr').length);
var total_general = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < cont_fila; i++) {
    var subtotal = $('#Subtotal_' + i).val();
    if(subtotal)
        total_general = parseFloat(total_general) + parseFloat(subtotal);
    }
$("#detalle_total").html("<strong><FONT color='#1b5e20' SIZE=6> " + (total_general * 1).toFixed(2) + " </FONT>");
}
```